# Having input be specifically in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: php, validation

How would i apply an if statement in an input field if i want the input to be exactly in MM/DD/YYYY format? Any other input that is different from this format i would echo out an error statement.

Comment: A regular expression is the way to go, but are you also trying to validate if they entered the month as the first number and day as the second number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expresion for that:

```
if (preg_match('#^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d$#', $str)) {
```

The `#` are just preg_match delimiters. The `^` and `$` mark start and end for the subject to match. And each `\d` is a placeholder which will match a decimal. The `/` are literal slashes which preg_match will test for.

You could also add `(` capture `)` groups to test the individual decimal blocks for conformity. I would do that separately to check for alternating formats. But for your purposes, it could be:

```
if (preg_match('#^(0\d|10|11|12)/([0-2]\d|30|31)/(19|20)\d\d$#', $str)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a dropdown box?  One for the month, one for the day, one for the year.

Comment: i was thinking of a date picker instead